# to initialize selection bar in UIPickerview?

Tags: iphone

How can i initialize selection bar in UIPickerview, when i run it, it shows ,first row is selected with bar..how can i change the row inwhich selection bar must be there dynamically?

i have done like following ...its not working?

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 

      {

        [psportPicker selectRow:3 inComponent:component animated:YES];
        return [citycount];


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call *selectRow* from *viewDidAppear* on the parent view controller.  I encountered the same problem when I was calling *selectRow* from *viewDidLoad*.  Move your *selectRow* into *viewDidAppear* and the *UIPickerView* will respond appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
[picker selectRow:[self.pickerData indexOfObject:indexToSelect] inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

See the [UIPickerView  Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) for details.

Comment: You have to call [picker selectRow...]; in your viewDidLoad or not in one of the picker delegates.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to select a certain row programmatically?

In that case, try `-selectRow:inComponent:animated:` (see [the documentation for UIPickerView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006842-CH3-SW8).

Answer (score 0):

You can call *selectRow* from *viewDidLoad* after *[super viewDidLoad]* on the parent view controller.  Your *UIPickerView* property should be properly initialized at that point.